# How to structure a proper SQL subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to wrap my head around how to do a proper subquery, it's not making sense to me, lets say I have two tables `books` and `chapters`:

Books

```
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+
| id | name             | author   | last_great_chapters |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+
| 1  | some book title  | john doe |                   2 |
| 2  | foo novel title  | some guy |                   4 |
| 3  | other book title | lol man  |                   3 |
+----+------------------+----------+---------------------+
```

Chapters

```
+----+---------+----------------+
| id | book_id | chapter_number |
+----+---------+----------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1              |
| 2  | 1       | 3              |
| 3  | 1       | 4              |
| 4  | 1       | 5              |
| 5  | 2       | 1              |
| 6  | 2       | 2              |
| 7  | 2       | 3              |
| 8  | 2       | 4              |
| 9  | 2       | 5              |
| 10 | 3       | 1              |
| 11 | 3       | 2              |
| 12 | 3       | 3              |
| 13 | 3       | 4              |
| 14 | 3       | 5              |
+----+---------+----------------+
```

How can I join the two tables, and just print out the number of rows (sorted limit(last_great_chapters)) of the "last_great_chapters" from the books table list for each book?

Comment: Would you please add your expected output?

Comment: What column `last_great_chapters` is referring from `chapter` table ? I think value is mismatched or not listed correctly.

Comment: It's great that you've provided examples of your source tables, but I don't think you've sufficiently explained what output you require or the logic which would explain it. As it stands, it's very unclear what you mean with this question.

Comment: This is my guess about what you mean. You want to list the books with a row for each chapter where the chapter is in the final X chapters of the book, where X is the number from the column `last_great_chapters`. Is that it?

Comment: Are you looking for a count of rows in the chapters table for each row in the book table? Or are you looking for a SUM of last_greatest_chapters? or something else? Just trying to help prompt you to what we need to provide a good answer.

Comment: Voting to close this as the question is unclear and OP is not responding to questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understood correctly, you want to print out table books and last_great_chapters count in  Chapters table?

if yes, try it

```
select b.id, b.name, b.author , b.last_great_chapter, COUNT(c.chapter_number) as rownumbers FROM Books as b
    LEFT JOIN Chapters AS C ON c.chapter_number = b.last_great_chapters
    group by b.id, b.name, b.author , b.last_great_chapter
```